# GridView vs. TableLayout | Android

Tags: android

Hello
I want to create month-view calendar for android with clickable days. What kind of layout/view should I use, TableLayout or GridView. I didn't find any examples for this...

Thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say `GridView` especially if you plan on putting all of your Calendar data in a `ContentProvider` for sharing with other apps.  You can then use your the provider and adapters to fill in the GridView dynamically

Comment: @schwiz i have used GridView in my project but i doesnot want to scroll in GridView. kindly suggest what i do.

Answer (score 2):

Check the fallowing tutorial on GridView:

http://www.firstdroid.com/2011/02/06/android-tutorial-gridview-with-icon-and-text/

After understanding this tutorial, just add the fallowing lines at the end of the  `onCreate` method:

```
grid_main.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, 
                            long id) {

        // Add your code here, you receive the index, 
        // you can start an intent or do whatever you wanted 
        // to do with the button

     }/* End of onItemClick */
});
```

BR,

Adrian.